# Configuracion de ATOM

Tags: configuración, atom-editor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Cada vez que pego un texto en ATOM este se va corrido a la izquierda haciendo dificil la lectura
que hago para poner un max de letras para que automaticamente se vaya a otra linea ? soy nuevo en estas tecnologias

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ejemplo]

Hola José, en atom como en otros editores puede usar esta opción para que te acomode el texto al tamaño de la ventana, espero que te sirva.
Saludos!